Python Rasa train not compatible with M3 Apple
Unable to run the "rasa train" in mac m3 terminal..
giving below error.
2024-06-26 17:27:12 INFO     rasa.cli.train  - Started validating domain and training data...
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  rasa train
After some research i have noticed this is a common issue in Apple M2 mac.
How to mitigate this.
i am in middle of running major project.
